# Umbraco 7: Set dynamic body class in body tag

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco7

What is the best way to set a dynamic body class? Tried:

```
<body class="@Umbraco.Field("pageTitle", altFieldAlias: "pageName")">
```

But this returns the page name like:

```
<body class="Some Page Name">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In reference to your example - that is the expected result since you are requesting the pageTitle property data from your document. That's not really suitable for a class name for teh reason you shown - it can contain spaces and invalid characters.

The property to use depends on what sort of css hook you need. You could use the DocumentTypeAlias as that has no spaces but is more general or if you need a class per page you could use a string that includes the document id which you know is unique. You can't use the id alone as I'm pretty sure css classes cannot begin with a numberic value.

Some examples from a v6 install which I had to hand but I think is still relevant in v7:

**Use the doctype alias:**

```
<body class="@Model.Content.DocumentTypeAlias.ToLower()">
```

**Use the document id for uniqueness:**

```
<body class="@string.Concat("pg-", Model.Content.Id)">
```

**Gets a property from the current document that contains the classes to add:**

```
<body class="@Umbraco.Field("bodyCssClasses")">
```

Comment: Thanks ProNotion! I used `<body class="@string.Concat("pg-", Model.Content.Id)">`